# Calling a function within a class with pool.map with one argument and self: TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'

Tags: python, threadpool

I'm trying to call a function within a class from another function within the same class with pool map

```
pool = Pool(num_cores)
res = pool.map(self.get_data_vector())
```

The function has no arguments except self and I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'
```

This is the function

```
def get_data_vector(self):
```

EDIT:

I was missing the variable to map which is self.doc_ids and it is a list.

I'm now calling it like this

```
res = pool.map(__class__.get_data_vector,(self,self.doc_ids))
```

The function should be called like this

```
def get_data_vector(self, doc_id):
```

but the error now changed to

```
TypeError: get_data_vector() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc_id'
```

Comment: `map` needs *two* parameters: the function, *and* the iterable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but how would be the iterable here if the function only receives self?

Comment: then this is not a case for a `map`, a `map` converts an iterable to a new iterable where it applies a function on *every* element.

Comment: If not map, is there any other option to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: well what are you trying to do?

Comment: `map` would apply the entire function in the first parameter to an entire iterable in the second paramater , `map(do this, to everything in this)`

Comment: I was making a mistake so I changed the problem in the edit. I still have trouble calling a function that needs one argument and the self as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that `self.doc_ids` is a list or something else iterable.

Then you should be able to use this:

```
res = pool.map(self.get_data_vector, self.doc_ids)
```

This means that `get_data_vector` will be called with two arguments.  The first one is `self`, as a bound method, and the second one are the elements of the iterable `self.doc_ids`.